# Adding all values of 2 stacks to 1 stack and sorting them

Tags: algorithm, sorting, stack

There are 3 stacks - A, B, C

Stacks A and B are sorted (the number on the top of the stack is the biggest).
Stack C is Empty
Only 5 operation are allowed:

```
push
pop 
top 
is_empty
create
```

We need to write a function that receives the stacks A and B, moves all the numbers in stacks A and B to stack C and stack C must be sorted (biggest Number is on top).

Comment: Is stack C unsorted or empty?

Comment: Also, what have you tried? Good [so] questions should show an attempt at solving the problem yourself.

Comment: -1 for not showing any effort.

Comment: what create operation supposed to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first cut, split the problem into two parts:

- Move elements from A and B into C, with the least element being at the top.
- Convert C with least element at the top into C with the highest element at the top i.e. reverse the sort order.

Once you have this, you can see if there is a better/more efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

look up the [towers of hanoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi), a standard problem/puzzle.

Comment: of course it does. actually the puzzle is precisely what your program is supposed to model. hint: try to match objects from the problem descriptions with code entities. if you don't succeed, go by numbers.

Comment: I just need the way to go by knowing how to move them  ..
1.) to move them all to stack C and then sort them 
2.) to pop a value from the top of A and a Value from the top of B and see who is bigger and insert them to C ..

Which one?

Comment: @WaseemGabour The towers of hanoi problem is *precisely* what you need to solve this. If a stack of discs has nothing to do with stacks then nothing does. If you're still having trouble visualizing the equivalence to your problem, imagine a modification of the towers of hanoi problem in which the discs are stacked with the largest on top and must be moved to the third peg (stack C) with the largest on top.

Comment: thank you .. but can anybody write the code for it ? without using structs ..
just with the 5 operations ..

Comment: It's a **less restrictive** Towers of Hanoi **variation** (the ordering isn't required at every step and the starting position is different). This may be enough for a different approach to be more efficient.

Comment: @Dukeling you're right of course. sorry for any confusion created. Waseem Gabour: you can still go by the book to get more info & hints for any solution, regardless of its efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

As stacks are sorted, you can apply merge sort mechanism. My thoughts are similar to user1930928. But adding this for more clarity and extension of data reversal.

Algorithm is as follows

1. Compare top of A with top of B
2. Pop the least element and push to stack C
3. Repeat step 2 until any of the stack ( A or B) becomes empty
4. Move remaining elements from non-empty stack to C. 
   Now you have all the elements in C but in ascending order. (That is least element at top).
5. Move all the elements from C to A.  (Contents in A are in descending order)
6. Move all the elements from A to B.  (Contents in B are in ascending order)
7. Move all the elements from B to C.

Now the contents of C are in the sorted descending order, which is the desired result.

I would encourage you to try writing the program. I can write if you really want.

Comment: While (!is_empty(a)) 
{
if (top(a)>top(b))    push (c,pop(a))
else if (top(a)<top(b))   push (c,pop(b))

if (!is_empty(b)  push(c,pop(b))

else ( the teacher said that if there are 2 equal numbers we just insert one of them to C)

while (!is_empty(c))
push(a,pop(c))

while (!is_empty(a))
push(b,pop(a))

while (!is_empty(b))
push(c,pop(b))